# Mathematica for professional use

Tags: licensing

I would like to buy Mathematica for professional use (and I guess I am the only one who would be using that as of now). I deal mainly with *math, physics, imaging and optics calculations*. I have been using Mathematica for nearly 4 years in University. Whereas, my workplace offered me MATLAB (along with statistical and computational analysis toolbox).

Its not really difficult to get into MATLAB but paying $1000.00 for each toolbox dint really stick with me. Plus I am way more used to with Mathematica for any kind of computational analysis and you do get everything you need within Mathematica instead of paying extra (Please correct me if I'm wrong here).

[image: Editions-Wolfram-Mathematica]

Question (updated):
Is Standard Desktop/Cloud (Mathematica Online) good enough for a professional use or should I go for the Enterprise ($7000.00) ? Will it also come with "[Optics Solutions](http://www.wolfram.com/solutions/industry/optics/)"?

PS: Disregard the tag on this post, I could not find the appropriate tag for this question.

Comment: I am afraid such a question is off topic here.  "Is it good enough for my needs?" is much too subjective.  To know more about the differences between the editions, you should ask Wolfram (although I believe that the *offline* functionality of the desktop version is identical).  It is not at all clear what that "Optics Solutions" thing is, but I do not think it is a package for which it makes sense to ask if it comes with M. It looks like a marketing page which basically says: the included functions can *also* be used for optics stuff, although they are not specialized for it.

Comment: I don't think that optics solutions is bundled with any of the versions you mentioned above.

Comment: [Optica](https://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/optica/) is something different that is not made by Wolfram, and you need to buy it separately.  But that marketing page seems strange: I don't think M has anything ready-made that lets you "Quickly simulate behavior of lenses, mirrors, and other optical components", but it certainly has many high level functions that allow you to implement this yourself.

Comment: @Szabolcs and 'Happy Fish' : Yes I thought this is going to be an off-topic post, thanks for clarifying the 'Optics Solutions' part. Should I remove/delete the post?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes I am sure Mathematica have very high level functionalities that would help me achieve what optica does. Thanks

Comment: I suggest you ask on http://community.wolfram.com/ . There it is not off topic.  I find that marketing page quite confusing to be honest ...